# call controller in JavascriptMVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, javascriptmvc

I have two controllers, `init`:

```
jQuery.Controller.extend('App.Controllers.Init', {  
    onDocument: true  

},{  
    load: function() {  
        //call App.Controllers.Tabs on $('#tabs')  
        //it is not that easy as $('#tabs').tabs() -> Throws: Object doesn't support this property or method  
    }
});
```

And `tabs`:

```
jQuery.Controller.extend('App.Controllers.Tabs,...
```

How to call tabs in init?

Comment: Quick note: Use 4 spaces for a code block, and outside of that 2 trailing spaces for a line break :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:
`$('#tabs').app_tabs()`
Just cut the "controller" word out. Make all letters lowercase, and change dots "." to "_"
One More Example:
controller definition:
`jQuery.Controller.extend('Appname.Controllers.Controllername',...`
call it:
`$('#some_id').appname_controllername();`