# How do you call a function from a jQuery controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, controller, javascriptmvc

I'm using JavascriptMVC and have a controller of the form

```
$.Controller.extend('AppName.Controllers.ControllerName',
{
  onDocument: true
}
{
  initControllerName: function() {
    ...
  },
  testFucntion1() {
    alert('yeah!!');
  }
});
```

and I'd like to be able to call the function testFunction1() from the page generated by my view.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623728/call-controller-in-javascriptmvc) which seems to be asking the same thing, but I wasn't able to figure it out with the answer provided there.

I've tried

```
$('#controllername').testFunction1();
$('#ppame_controllername').testFunction1();
$('#ppame_controllers.controllername').testFunction1();
```

without success.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your function with:

```
$(document).app_name_controller_name("testFunction1");
```

If you want to pass arguments to your function specify them after the function name:

```
$(document).app_name_controller_name("testFunction1", "Hello World");
```

The `onDocument: true` in the static section of your controller definition means that it is automatically attached to the document element, so that is how you get an instance of it. If you want to bind it to something else remove `onDocument: true` and use something like:

```
$('#main').app_name_controller_name();
```

That will create an instance of your controller and attach it to the $('#main') element. That element is then available in the controller's methods via `this.element`.

I don't know your situtation but you shouldn't really need to call controller methods very often - the controller should bind to events that are triggered by DOM elements and published by models. JMVC makes it very easy to bind controller methods to events: [Listening To Events](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jquery.controller.listening)

Comment: thanks for your answer! Your right, my situation is sort of a hack and I will need to do a lot of refactoring some point :). I've been using the controller to store utility type functions in addition to just event binding - should those utility functions just go in a general script file which is referenced by the controller? How do you recommend (from a design perspective) to organize this?

Comment: nm! I figured out why I was confusing myself - I was catching an even on an object directly instead of catching it in the controller which is why I needed the hack in the first place and I've since fixed the problem. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I put utility code in classes defined with $.Class rather than $.Controller and load them up in a call to steal(). I keep them in the main app namespace: $.Class.extend('AppName.Utilities.DateConverter', {});

Comment: How do we get just a return value of the method, Say 'testFunction1'. say something like this if I want `x= app_name_controller_name("testFunction1")`, When I do this , it says undefined function...!

Answer (score 1):

Martin Owen's answer is accurate except I found app_name_controller_name confusing at first.

A real example would be:

if your controller is defined like

```
$.Controller.extend('Layout.Controllers.Page', 
  ...
```

then use

```
$(document).layout_page("testFunction1");
```

Layout = app_name

Page = controller_name